# Is it possible to change a hero image depending on the users location?

Tags: jquery, geolocation

Basically, I am creating a landing page for Scotland and Ireland. If a user coming from Scotland views the landing page, I would like the hero to display an image of Scotland and the same logic if the user was viewing from Ireland.

Currently, this is what I am working with. The code below is for any users, viewing from Ireland. I'm assuming this isn't working because of the long and lat.

```
    var body = document.body;

    function locate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                if (position.coords.latitude >= 53.1424 && position.coords.longitude >= 7.6921) {
                    $('.main-image-slider').css('background-image', 'url(/Destinations/Ireland_D15/GiantsCauseway_P2604/giants-causeway-19186.jpg)');
                } 
                else {
                    $('.main-image-slider').css('background-image', 'url(/Destinations/Scotland_D130/General/glenfinnan-railway-viaduct-19900.jpg)');
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log(false);
        }
    };

    locate();
```

Comment: have tried to debug the code? what's the output of `position.coords`? what do you expect? Is your console reporting any error?

Comment: no errors - ideally I want to target the whole of Ireland but not sure how to do that - so I used long and lat

Comment: Draw a bounding box around the island, than check if lat and long of the user are included

Comment: you could also use a geo location service via ajax and depending on the response, just apply different classes to you wrapper

Comment: @fcalderan trying the bounding box - ill let you know how it goes and cheers Alex - something I will consider if this does not work

Comment: The other idea can be get the user's location based on the IP address. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/2/   But this will fail when user is using any proxies. If your users are not so technical then you can use this.

Comment: @fcalderan using the bounding box to highlight the whole area worked a treat. Thanks for all the other idea guys.